# Secure upload for Wordpress comments

Tags: wordpress, security, plugins, upload, comments

I liked the functionality provided by the Easy Comment Uploads Wordpress plugin.  However, I see that it has been removed from the Wordpress plugin repository, I'm guessing for security reasons but I can't seem to confirm that anywhere.  There was a security issue with an early version of the plugin but I haven't seen any reports of problems with version 1.01 which I have.  Anyways does anyone know if this plugin is secure, and/or if there are any other secure plugins (free or premium) that provide similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the author of the plugin, I can confirm that the latest version of the plugin (1.01) contains no known security issues, although you should replace the version of the timthumb.php script which is included with the plugin with the newest available version.

I have been too busy recently to work on the plugin so I am afraid that it is unlikely to be updated any time soon, although I am currently involved with developing a premium plugin which offers much of the same functionality, and a lot more besides including a much more security focused design: http://www.solaceten.info/plugins/wp-extra-comment-fields-v2/ .